# PyCharm не видит последнюю версию интерпретатора Python

Tags: python, pycharm

Больше года не работал с Python и выскочила странная вещь. За это время система (Fedora) много раз обновляась и сейчас версия у меня 3.9. Что подтверждается просто:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.9.2
```

Эту версию и видим в каталоге /usr/bin

```
$ pwd
/usr/bin
$ ls python*
python        python2-config    python3.9-x86_64-config           python-argcomplete-tcsh
python2       python3       python3-config                python-config
python2.7     python3.9     python3-html2text                 python-html2text
python2.7-config  python3.9-config  python-argcomplete-check-easy-install-script
```

Это присказка. Сказка же заключается в том, что есть питоновский скрипт, который давным-давно отлажен и работает. В него я вставил печать версии интерпретатора. При запуске видим вот что:

```
$ python Launch.py 
Версия интерпретатора:   3.9.2 (default, Feb 20 2021, 00:00:00)
```

Как и следует из здравого смысла. Но, если я пытаюсь запустить тот же самый скрипт в рамках проекта PyCharm, то выдаётся вот такое сообщение:

```
Версия интерпретатора:   3.8.7 (default, Nov 10 2011, 15:00:00)
```

И ничего не работает. Если пытаться в свойствах проекта изменить текущий интерпретатор, то PyCharm просто **не виидит** последнюю версию:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно предположить, что эта ахинея достаётся из каких-то кэшенй PyCharm. Я полностью снёс каталог .PyCharm в домашней директории, но это не помогло.

Как исправить сиьуацию?

Comment: Можно попробовать проверить какие права/владелец для файла python3.9 стоят, и чем они отличаются от прав у других версий python.

Comment: Вообще, лучше создать виртуальную среду с нужной версией питона для проекта. И подключить интерпретатор из виртуальной среды в Pycharm. Дополнительно, все используемые библиотеки будут только в пределах этой виртуальной среды. `python3 -m venv <env>`. Это защитит Вас от глобальных изменений.

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно у вас неверно выставлено виртуальное окружение в самом pycharm.Посмотрите какое именно у вас виртуальное окружение выставлено( находится в file-->settings-->project interpreter).

Прикладываю screenshot
[image: Скрин pycharm]

Comment: - "Посмотрите какое именно у вас виртуальное окружение выставлено( находится в file-->settings-->project interpreter)."

- Так проблема как раз в том, что находясь именно **в этом** окне выбора интерпретатора, PyCharm видит что-то нереальное: версию 3.8 видит, хотя она у меня **не** установлена и не видит версию 3.9, хотя я с ней работаю из командной строки.

Я понимаю, что проблема в venv. Я полностью снёс этот каталог в каталоге проекта. Не помогает. Где-то есть venv всего PyCharm, но я не могу найти эту заразу...

Comment: тогда сделайте версию 3.9 дефолтной в самой системе,делали?

Comment: "сделайте версию 3.9 дефолтной в самой системе".  Так я же в самом вопросе говорил, что если я вызываю python из консоли, то печатается версия 3.9.2. А если из PyCharm, то 3.8.Но в реальности, 3.8. на компе нет. Поэтому PyCharm не работает. Но, тем не менее, версию 3.9 почему-то не видит...

Comment: Интересно=) А в терминале из под окружения проекта какую версию показывает?То есть если вызвать версию из под source/bin/activate ?Я бы снес обе версии ,сохранив нужное окружение в requirements.txt,потом бы поставил одну нужную и туда бы pip install -r requirements.txt установил все нужное

Comment: Честно говоря, из того, что вы написали, не понял почти ничего. :-( Похоже, что PyCharm был установлен из пакета типа flatpak в каком-=то своём виртуалном окружении, которое сейчас накрылось медным тазом. Не зря я с таким подозрением относился к этим flatpak-ам. 

Попробую всё переустановить всё с нуля. Может найду нормальный rpm пакет...

Comment: Обнаружил, что из меню приложений PyCharm действительно запускается как flatpak. Убрал. Установил нормальный PyCharm, отконфигуировал его на python-3.9 и всё работает...